# Xamarin Forms webview not working on IOS at all

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, webview

I am working in a cross-platform application.

I use a cross-platform webview https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview

it is working fine on Android

but nothing works on IOS

No events fire at all, even the "OnNavigationError" event.

I used a "WebRequest" to check if I can access the internet, and it works fine, no connection problems.

I set WidthRequest and HeightRequest for the webview.

also I set NS security for IOS project

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>
```

I tried "https://www.google.com" and it did not work.

The problem for me is that is just silent, no errors at all.

Can anyone help, please?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I find the solution :)

I was just missing a single line in `AppDelegate.cs` on IOS project
this is the problem's solution in case someone else faces it like me

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    ..
    Xam.Plugin.WebView.iOS.FormsWebViewRenderer.Initialize();
    ..
}
```

Comment: Wondering  what is 'Xam' in Xam.Plugin.WebView.iOS.FormsWebViewRenderer.Initialize(), is it a parameter to method 'FinishedLaunching' or attribute in  'AppDelegate.cs '?

Comment: It is for the plugin, just install the plugin first from https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview